# How to do java basic program in aws?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to try out java in aws, specifically lambda.

I don't know much java so hoping to learn it in this endeavor. Please be gentle to a newbie

Trying to get hello world working so I can start iterating but I don't know the syntax.

My java program:

```
$ cat helloWorld.java 
class helloWorld
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

I zip it up with `zip java above_program.java`

The call i make in the lambda is to `helloWorld::main`

The result I currently get when I test it is

```
START RequestId: 32ef4680-b741-402d-9af7-7c0b0c9e5f1f Version: $LATEST
Class not found: helloWorld: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: helloWorld
```

Comment: zip javac you mean? have you compiled it?

Comment: Not sure how it works in aws but you can try to append publuc keyword before your class i.e. `public class HelloWorld`. Also i think you would need to complie your class using `javac` command first.

Comment: yes i need to compile the file - and then learn about `--version 8` for use in aws lambda. Now i get a different error. sop the main answer here was to compile the file and upload the compiled file. i had assumed uploading the source and that lambda would compile it (say on upload), but seems not.

Comment: So is your problem resolved already? Whats the new error :-)

Comment: Hi it is https://stackoverflow.com/q/58651788/631619 :)

Answer (score 1):

Lambda will not compile and run your java code by only uploading the file to lambda, for compilation language you have to upload complete package where for interpreter language like python you just need upload the code and also you will able to edit code in the console editor for python or nodejs etc but the same feature is applicable for complication language, you have to upload the deployment package.

**AWS Lambda Deployment Package in Java**

> Your deployment package can be a **.zip** file or a **standalone jar**; it is
>   your choice. You can use any build and packaging tool you are familiar
>   with to create a deployment package.

We provide examples of using Maven to create standalone jars and using Gradle to create a .zip file. For more information, see the following topics:

**Topics**

[Creating a .jar Deployment Package Using Maven without any IDE (Java)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-no-ide.html)

[Creating a .jar Deployment Package Using Maven and Eclipse IDE (Java)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-and-eclipse.html)

[Creating a ZIP Deployment Package for a Java Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html)

[Authoring Lambda Functions Using Eclipse IDE and AWS SDK Plugin (Java)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-author-using-eclipse-sdk-plugin.html)

You can read more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)