# aws - java8 - Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

java newbie.

I've compiled with java 8

```
javac HelloWorld.java --release 8
```

and uploaded the complied file as the aws lambda code.

Why am I getting the error when i run it in aws lambda?

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }   
}
```

#### Error

```
An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@ae45eb6; line: 1, column: 1]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@ae45eb6; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
```

Comment: Note: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are written in PascalCase. `helloWorld` should be `HelloWorld`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thank You.  I did that, but same error.  Updated.

Comment: In non-aws world your program looks perfect. :) See if you find it related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545642/error-executing-hello-world-for-aws-lambda-in-java

Comment: May be you need to implement RequestHandler and override handleRequest function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda provides limited Java runtime to execute AWS Java Lambda handlers. The limitations are logical like access to file system, etc for security purposes as the code runs in a shared multi-tenanted environment. In order to execute a program, your class should implement the `RequestHandler` interface and implement the `handleRequest` method. Here is the sample from the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html)

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Integer, String>{
  public String handleRequest(Integer myCount, Context context) {
    return String.valueOf(myCount);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something fundamental here. You can't just throw a class or jar file at Lambda. There's a well-defined interface between the Lambda service and your code. Think of it this way: Lambda launches a JVM, and Lambda itself implements a Java class with the static `main` method (in its code, not your code) and executes that. That `main` method will ultimately call your configured Lambda function's entry point. I'd recommend this [Hello World tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/run-serverless-code/).